# Excel to a remote oracle database with largish data sets (>2000 records).  Stored proc call with a driver that supports FetchSize

Tags: sql, oracle, excel

```
Public Const connString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;FetchSize=200;CacheType=Memory;" & _
    "Password=" & db_password & ";User ID=" & db_user & _
    ";Data Source=" & db_source

Sub GetEncyclopediaData()
    Dim MyConnection As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim MyResults As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim MyCommand As New ADODB.Command


    MyConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    MyConnection.Open

    MyCommand.ActiveConnection = MyConnection

    MyCommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    MyCommand.CommandText = "MKT_OWNER.ETP.p_ETPEncyclopedia"

  '  ETPEncyclopediaCommand.CommandType = adCmdText
  '  ETPEncyclopediaCommand.CommandText = "{ CALL MKT_OWNER.ETP.p_ETPEncyclopedia () }"

    MyCommand.Properties("PLSQLRSet") = True
    Set MyResults = MyCommand.Execute
    MyCommand.Properties("PLSQLRSet") = False

    While Not MyResults.EOF

        MyResults.MoveNext
    Wend


End SubEnd Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

When using ADO in stored procedure mode, pass only the stored procedure name as the text:

```
MyCommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
MyCommand.CommandText = "MKT_OWNER.ETP.p_ETPEncyclopedia"
```

Alternatively, in text mode, you get to pass a query:

```
MyCommand.CommandType = adCmdText
MyCommand.CommandText = "{ CALL MKT_OWNER.ETP.p_ETPEncyclopedia () }"
```

Comment: (From a rejected edit by davidvnyc): I tried [the first suggestion].  I don't get the error on MyResults.EOF, but I don't get any rows either. When i run this stored proc with the MSDAORA driver in excel it works fine. I get back rows. This reason I am using the OraOLEDB.Oracle driver is because of the FetchSize option.

Comment: @davidvnyc: Are you sure your connection string contains `Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;` ?  Try to disable `PLSQLRSet` right after you call `Execute` (most [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558714/how-do-i-call-an-oracle-stored-procedure-from-an-excel-vba-script/4558786#4558786) seem to do that.)   @Brian: Thanks :)

Comment: @Brian - I tried your suggestion. ETPEncyclopediaResults.EOF regurns true on the first hit. @Adomar I set the provider  asmyConnection.Provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle" Also, i switch the PLSQLRSet property to false, doesn't work.

Comment: @davidvnyc: Does it help if you set the provider inside the connection string, not later through a property?

Comment: @davidvnyc: I was not making a suggestion.  I was reproducing the text of your rejected edit so that Andomar could see it.

Comment: The basic problem here is with calling an oracle stored proc from excel. The use case I have is a stored proc that returns 3000 rows from a remote oracle database. There is a big performance hit if the client isn't setup to buffer the data "FetchSize".  I have a setup that works, but performs very slowly with the MSDAORA driver.  It's my understanding that MSDAORA doesn't support a FetchSize.  Any driver that I can get to work that supports FetchSize should solve the problem.

Comment: The code sample has just been updated to reflect all the suggestions.  It runs without error, but return zero rows.  The stored proc when run in java or dbArtisan returns over 3000

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have to use ADODB, but I personally prefer Oracle solution:

```
Dim OO4OSession As OraSession
Set OO4OSession = New OraSessionClass

Dim db As OraDatabase
Set db = OO4OSession.OpenDatabase("DEV02", "dev/dev_demo", 0)

db.Parameters.Add "CLIENT_ID", "1", ORAPARM_INPUT

Dim ds As OraDynaset
Set ds = db.CreateDynaset("SELECT NAME FROM CLIENT WHERE CLIENT_ID = :CLIENT_ID", 0)


db.Close

Set db = Nothing
Set OO4OSession = Nothing
```

Good documantation is avaialble [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28378/basfeat.htm)