# Oracle ORA-06550 identifier must be declared when called from ADO Command Object

Tags: oracle, vba, stored-procedures, ado, adodb

I am trying to use Access / VBA to retrieve a resultset from my Oracle stored procedure, using an ADO Command object.

I keep receiving the error:

```
[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-06550: line 1, column 19:
PLS-00201: identifier 'RETURNDATA' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I've read a number of articles on the net about how its done - and have tried different ways of doing it (ie. using execute instead of a command object) but I just cannot seem to get it to work.

Microsoft had a good knowledge base article on how to perform this - but despite following their example - I cannot seem to get it to work.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176086

When I *Run PL/SQL* in Oracle SQL Developer, the return value is listed in the *Output Variables* window.  This tells me that both the stored procedure is working, and the necessary permissions have been granted.

**Oracle Version:**

SELECT * FROM v$version

```
Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
"CORE   9.2.0.8.0   Production"
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 9.2.0.8.0 - Production
```

**Oracle Package Definition:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE test AUTHID DEFINER AS
  PROCEDURE testSP (returnData OUT NUMBER);
END test;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE BODY test AS
  PROCEDURE testSP (returnData OUT NUMBER) IS
    BEGIN
      returnData := 7;
    END;
END test;
```

**MS Access VBA Code**

```
Public Sub testSP()
  Dim oraConn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim oraCmd As ADODB.Command
  Dim oraRetSet As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim oraNum As Integer

  Set oraConn = New ADODB.Connection

  ' Discovered I need to set this to Read/Write or the SP cannot do any INSERT operations
  oraConn.Mode = adModeReadWrite

  ' Connect to the Oracle Server
  oraConn.Open "Driver={Oracle in OraHome102};dbq=oradsn;Uid=username;Pwd=password"

  ' Set up our Command.
  Set oraCmd = New ADODB.Command
  Set oraCmd.ActiveConnection = oraConn
  oraCmd.CommandType = adCmdText
  oraCmd.Parameters.Append oraCmd.CreateParameter("returnData", adNumeric, adParamOutput)
  oraCmd.CommandText = "{CALL test.testSP({resultset 1, returnData})}"

  ' Set up our Recordset
  Set oraRetSet = New ADODB.Recordset
  oraRetSet.CursorType = adOpenStatic

  ' Attach our Recordset to our Command
  Set oraRetSet.Source = oraCmd

  ' Open our Recordset
  oraRetSet.Open

  ' Retreive our Stored Procedure Result
  oraNum = oraRetSet.Fields(0).Value

  ' Display Result to user
  Debug.Print ">>> Return Value: " & oraNum

  ' Close the Recordset & Connection Objects
  oraRetSet.Close
  oraConn.Close

  ' Clean Up
  Set oraConn = Nothing
  Set oraCmd = Nothing
  Set oraRetSet = Nothing

End Sub
```

I am really drawing blanks - which means its probably something small that I missed.  Any help would be appreciated.

**Update Aug 29**
I have made no progress.   I tried to switch from ODBC to the OLEDB Provider, following another stackoverflow question / answer as a guide:

[How do I call an Oracle stored procedure from an Excel VBA script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558714/how-do-i-call-an-oracle-stored-procedure-from-an-excel-vba-script)

```
' Connect to the Oracle Server
oraConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=oradsn;" & _
                 "User ID=username;Password=password;"
oraConn.Open

Set oraCmd = New ADODB.Command
Set oraCmd.ActiveConnection = oraConn
oraCmd.Parameters.Append oraCmd.CreateParameter("returnData", adSmallInt, adParamOutput)
oraCmd.Properties("PLSQLRSet") = True
oraCmd.CommandText = "{CALL test.testSP(?)}"
Set oraRetSet = oraCmd.Execute
oraCmd.Properties("PLSQLRSet") = False

oraNum = oraRetSet.Fields(0).Value
```

This gets rid of the undeclared identifier, but it does not return any recordset ..  oraRetSet.Fields.Count equals 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out what was going on.

This website is what finally made the light turn on:
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php

I was trying to return a specific value - an error code. Using the recordset in ADO is more designed at returning a data set.

If you wish to return a cursor ref, as a recordset you need to set an OUT parameter to a cursor ref data type such as SYS_REFCURSOR.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE list_staff (r_stafflist OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS 
    BEGIN 
      OPEN r_stafflist FOR
        SELECT name,
               telephone,
               department
        FROM   stafflist
        ORDER BY name;
    END list_staff;
```

Then ADO will automatically bind to the ref cursor when the command is issued.  You don't add the cursor to the ADO Command object parameters.