# Execute PL/SQL insde Excel VBA

Tags: oracle, vba, plsql

am having a PL/SQL procedure like below:

```
create or replace procedure forecast_real_dates_procedure
IS
BEGIN
DELETE FROM FORECAST_REAL_DATES_TABLE;
insert into FORECAST_REAL_DATES_TABLE select * from FORECAST_REAL_DATES_VIEW;
END;
/
```

I want to execute this procedure inside a excel vba (i.e.), run the statement execute forecast_real_dates_procedure inside the vba. I have already done with connecting to oracle from vba and all those stuffs. But, just confused with the command to do this. Can anyone please help me on this.

thanks

Comment: Not sure with the VBA code, but just a thought that the delete query can be replaced with`TRUNCATE TABLE FORECAST_REAL_DATES_TABLE;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I call an Oracle stored procedure from an Excel VBA script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558714/how-do-i-call-an-oracle-stored-procedure-from-an-excel-vba-script)

Comment: hiMahesh, thanks for your reply. i dont have any problem with the code inside the procedure. Just need to execute this through vba..:)

Comment: @Shabalin...Hello, I do saw that post already. But i could not understand that clearly

Comment: @VinodChelladurai Then you should edit your question and list specific problems you are facing or subjects that are not clear.

Comment: @Shabalin..Hi, that code in general was too much confusing for me. And that's the reason i posted my question very cleaarly with example procedure also.

Comment: @VinodChelladurai Plese post VBA code you have so far and mark where exactly you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (not tested):

```
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command

con.provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle"
con.CursorLocation = adUseClient
con.Open "PLSQLRSet=0;Data Source=<YOUR_DATABASE>" , "<USER>", "<Password>"
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = con

cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "forecast_real_dates_procedure"
cmd.Execute
con.Close
```

You have to add the reference to you VBA Macro in: Tools -> References -> Enable "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.? Library"

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this.

Just do the following code

```
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
 .ActiveConnection = cn
 .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
 .CommandText = "forecast_real_dates_procedure"
 .Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
End With
```