# Return multiple rows from Oracle SQL Stored Procedure to Excel (VBA)

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, vba, stored-procedures

I'm trying to transfer an SQL query that is currently performed in Oracle SQL Developer (and then pasted into Excel) to Excel so it is called via VBA and a stored procedure.

The code to connect to the DB is as follows:
Sub ConnectToOracle()

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim arr As Variant

connstr = "Provider=msdaora;Data Source=###;User Id=###;Password=###;"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

cn.Open connstr

rs.CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
rs.Open ("select * from articles where artnr in (123, 234, 345)"), cn

arr = rs.GetRows
arr = transposeArray(arr)

Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
x = UBound(arr, 1) - LBound(arr, 1) + 1
y = UBound(arr, 2) - LBound(arr, 2) + 1

Worksheets(1).Activate
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(x, y)) = arr

'Close connections
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

This works perfectly. The code pulls me all the details for articles 123, 234, and 345 and pastes it into the Excel.

However, my SQL that should be replaced is around 500 lines of code and I don't want to hard code it into the VBA code but rather use a stored procedure. I have used them before on MSSQL, but never on Oracle.

How would I go about this? The only tutorials I find on youtube are showing how to return individual values. I, however, need an array to be returned.

Currently my stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_articles AS 
BEGIN

select
  *
from articles
where
  artnr in (123, 234, 345)
;

END get_articles;
```

But I don't know how to make it return the values to the Excel/VBA?

Thanks!

Comment: Here is the thread you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558714/how-do-i-call-an-oracle-stored-procedure-from-an-excel-vba-script

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I saw the thread before. However, it doesn't tell me how to setup the stored procedure. This link to the documentary only includes the one-line statements I was referring to. I would like to call a stored procedure featuring "select * from table" and get all the entries back into my Excel sheet