# identifier must be declared error when executing stored procedure in VB6

Tags: vba, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, vb6

```
ssqlstmt = "{Call STORED_PROCEDURE(" & INPUTPARAM & ")}"
iResult = objConnect.ExecuteSP(ssqlstmt, 1)
If iResult <> 0 Then    
        MsgBox "Error"
Else
        MsgBox "Success"
End If
```

Error Message:

> [Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
> PLS-00201: identifier 'STORED_PROCEDURE' must be declared
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: What type of object is `objConnect`?  Would be helpful to show more of the code for context.  Is your SP literally called "STORED_PROCEDURE" or is that a placeholder/redaction ?

Comment: Please [edit] the question with a [MRE] including: the DDL (`CREATE PROCEDURE`) statements for creating the procedure; what the `INPUTPARAM` value is.

Comment: See for a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558714/how-do-i-call-an-oracle-stored-procedure-from-an-excel-vba-script

Answer (score 1):

Such an error means either user has no access to that stored_procedure or the stored_procedure doesn't exist in the db.

0. Check the spelling. It would be really annoying to go through the next steps just because of some typo. And don't forget to check if the stored_procedure resides within a package. In this case you should call is using package's name:

   ```
   call STORED_PACKAGE.STORED_PROCEDURE
   ```
1. Login via sqlplus using credentials your program logs in with and try to call stored_procedure from there. I believe you'll face the same error message
2. Login as some more "powerful" (as a developer account or even as sys) user in order to see whether the procedure exists in the database and whether the user your VB-program uses has enough privileges to run the routine.